# JPA PostLoad and PreUpdate with Embedded columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, embedding

Situation: NotificationProfile entity has collection of NotificationProfileIntegration entities which has embedded IntegrationNotificationCutOff. It is legacy database and i cannot modify it. Someone thought it is a good idea to store time as "HH:mm" strings, but i need to work with date objects. That is the reason why i have these convert callbacks and transient date fields.

When i do (for existing profile entity)
`entityManager.merge(profile);`
I expect that @PreUpdate is called on NotificationProfileIntegration and dates are converted to their string representation and persisted to DB. Instead @PostLoad method is called first and @PreUpdate is called after.
So if i set something in cutOff instance it is never persisted, because in @PostLoad method new instance of cutOffs is created because it is null due to this feature of hibernate

> When all of the values in an @Embedded object are null, Hibernate will
>   set the field in the parent object to null.

How can i handle this situation? Thank you.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTIFICATION_PROFILES")
public class NotificationProfile extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "notificationProfile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<NotificationProfileIntegration> profileIntegrations;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTIFICATION_PROFILE_INTEG")
public class NotificationProfileIntegration extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @Embedded
    private IntegrationNotificationCutOff cutOffs;

    @Embedded
    private IntegrationNotificationAverageCount averageShipments;

    @PostLoad
    public void initEmbeded() {
        if (cutOffs == null) {
            cutOffs = new IntegrationNotificationCutOff();
        }
        if (averageShipments == null) {
            averageShipments = new IntegrationNotificationAverageCount();
        }
        cutOffs.convertToDates();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    private void formatCutOffs() {
        if (cutOffs != null) {
            cutOffs.convertToValues();
        }
    }
}


@Embeddable
public class IntegrationNotificationCutOff {

    @Column(name = "NPI_CUT_OFF_TIME_MON")
    private String monday;

    @Column(name = "NPI_CUT_OFF_TIME_TUE")
    private String tuesday;

    @Column(name = "NPI_CUT_OFF_TIME_WED")
    private String wednesday;

    @Column(name = "NPI_CUT_OFF_TIME_THU")
    private String thursday;

    @Column(name = "NPI_CUT_OFF_TIME_FRI")
    private String friday;

    @Column(name = "NPI_CUT_OFF_TIME_SAT")
    private String saturday;

    @Column(name = "NPI_CUT_OFF_TIME_SUN")
    private String sunday;

    @Transient
    private Date mondayDate;

    @Transient
    private Date tuesdayDate;

    @Transient
    private Date wednesdayDate;

    @Transient
    private Date thursdayDate;

    @Transient
    private Date fridayDate;

    @Transient
    private Date saturdayDate;

    @Transient
    private Date sundayDate;

    public void convertToDates() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = getDateFormat();
        mondayDate = nullSafeConvert(monday, dateFormat);
        tuesdayDate = nullSafeConvert(tuesday, dateFormat);
        wednesdayDate = nullSafeConvert(wednesday, dateFormat);
        thursdayDate = nullSafeConvert(thursday, dateFormat);
        fridayDate = nullSafeConvert(friday, dateFormat);
        saturdayDate = nullSafeConvert(saturday, dateFormat);
        sundayDate = nullSafeConvert(sunday, dateFormat);
    }

    public void convertToValues() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = getDateFormat();
        monday = nullSafeFormat(mondayDate, dateFormat);
        tuesday = nullSafeFormat(tuesdayDate, dateFormat);
        wednesday = nullSafeFormat(wednesdayDate, dateFormat);
        thursday = nullSafeFormat(thursdayDate, dateFormat);
        friday = nullSafeFormat(fridayDate, dateFormat);
        saturday = nullSafeFormat(saturdayDate, dateFormat);
        sunday = nullSafeFormat(sundayDate, dateFormat);
    }

    private String nullSafeFormat(Date date, SimpleDateFormat dateFormat) {
        if (date == null) {
             return null;
        }
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    private SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    }

    private Date nullSafeConvert(String day, SimpleDateFormat dateFormat) {
        if (day == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(day);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
It seems that embedding does not have any efect on this behavior. When i refactor it to single entity problem is still here: after calling createOrUpdate - select is triggered before an update and my change to entity is somewhere "lost"